# error in installing firebase with angular 9: firebase/app

Tags: angular, firebase, angular9

I am trying to install firebase in my angular 9 project.
i m following a tutorial on udemy and everything is working fine for now.
BUT, when i try installing firebase, this error shows up:
$ npm install firebase
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...anary.0fa319e.tgz","f'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sir. Berry\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-05-19T19_23_37_744Z-debug.log
[firebase error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6uP2.png)

Also, when i try ng serve: this error shows up:

ERROR in The target entry-point "@angular/fire" has missing dependencies:
 - firebase/app

Comment: can you provide "ng --version"?

Comment: hello Radik, I am using angular 9

Answer (score 0):

try

```
delete package-lock.json
delete `node_modules` folder
```

reinstall

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm i
```

Comment: $ npm i -S @angular/fire firebase
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...anary.0fa319e.tgz","f'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sir. Berry\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-19T20_54_52_756Z-debug.log

Comment: this is the error that i got after i tried your answer.. i don't understand this error

Comment: @SirajBerry some of package could be broken

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future. If possible it might be worth uninstalling all Firebase packages (firebase tools, firebase and angular/fire) by doing this

```
npm uninstall -g firebase-tools
npm uninstall firebase
npm uninstall angularfire --save
```

then

```
npm install rimraf -g 
rimraf node_modules
npm i
```

to clear out node modules and reinstall dependencies, then reinstall firebase tools, angular.fire and then the correct version of firebase that corresponds to angular/fire